# How to get stream of data from arduino serial monitor on Apache Edgent application (Java application)?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, arduino, java

> The sample java application for reading random sensor value is given
>   as:

```
package org.apache.edgent.samples.topology;
import java.util.Random;
import org.apache.edgent.function.Supplier;

/**
 * Every time get() is called, TempSensor generates a temperature reading.
 */
public class TempSensor implements Supplier<Double> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    double currentTemp = 65.0;
    Random rand;

    TempSensor(){
        rand = new Random();
    }
    @Override
    public Double get() {
        // Change the current temperature some random amount
        double newTemp = rand.nextGaussian() + currentTemp;
        currentTemp = newTemp;
        return currentTemp;
    }
}
```

> this example is given directly from Apache Edgent Samples which only 
>   generates random values but in order to access arduino via usb serial
>   communication, there is a SerialPort interface in
>   org.apache.edgent.connectors.serial package but unfortunately less
>   information is given in the documentation. And everytime I import
>   org.apache.edgent.connectors.serial package it shows compilation error
>   [image]
>   the code for which is given below:

```
package org.apache.edgent.samples.topology;

import org.apache.edgent.providers.direct.DirectProvider;
import org.apache.edgent.topology.TStream;
import org.apache.edgent.topology.Topology;
import org.apache.edgent.connectors.*;
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("write anything\n");

        String msg = sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("you have written:\n");

        DirectProvider dp = new DirectProvider();
        c
        Topology top = dp.newTopology();

        TStream<String> helloStream = top.strings(msg);

        helloStream.print();

    dp.submit(top);

        //code for reading sensor value from arduino goes below here

        DirectProvider dp2 = new DirectProvider();

        Topology top2 = dp2.newTopology();

        InputStream input = top2.getInput();
    input.print();
    dp2.submit(top2);
    }
}
```

> i know that the code is not correct, could anyone please guide me through 
>   this. thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Maven configuration is probably at fault by the looks of it but you would be better off asking this on a programming forum.  The fact that you are using a Raspberry PI is irrelevant to the problem you have here.

Comment: @JohnHawthorne could you please provide me steps to correctly configure Maven (which is in Apache Edgent)?

Comment: Have a read at the documentation here: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html

Comment: Thank you @JohnHawthorne for providing me with documentation but honestly i could not understand it properly, do i have to seperately download and install (and configure) maven? since maven is already there in Apache Edgent folder and i have run the command ./mvnw install to install it. is that the correct way?

Comment: Hi Arun, it would be cool if you could signup to our mailinglist dev@edgent.apache.org ... there I can help you. Unfortunately the part of the log you posted is missing the actual cause. I'm certain we will be able to sort this out there. Chris